# Web scraping click to download

Tags: javascript, python, html, python-requests, web-crawler

I would like to use Python to automate the following task:
given fileid 8426 and date 03312021

1. go to the website:
   https://cdr.ffiec.gov/Public/ViewFacsimileDirect.aspx?ds=call&idType=fdiccert&id=8426&date=03312021
2. click "Download PDF"
3. Save file to directory

I did some research and found a python module Request: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/

Looks like I should be able to declare a data object and pass it in order to send out the request

```
r = requests.post('https://my_url', data = {'key':'value'})
with open(test.pdf, "wb") as f:
   f.write(r.content)
```

However, I have trouble finding the proper attributes inside the data object in my case. I have tried some and unable to fetch the desired pdf file. Any help would be greatly appreciated !!

Comment: What is the result of f.write()?

Answer (score 0):

So.. in case of the `request.post()` method the `data` argument is the dictionary, that represents key-value pairs of the html post form. In order to find it you can to go on DevTools in your browser (shift-ctr-I in Chrome and Mozilla), open the Network tab and submit the form you need to inspect - in your case the form is represented as single `<input type="submit" ... >` element (stylized as "Download PDF" button). After you hit this input, browser will make well-formed POST-request to the server and you can see the correct html headers and key-values of that request on the Network tab - just grub it and form two dicts in your python script: first one with the headers and the second with the post-form values.

**An example with the url you posted ahead**

```
# http headers
headers = 
{'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
 'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,de;q=0.6',
 'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
 'Connection': 'keep-alive',
 'Content-Length': '1017',
 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
 'Cookie': 'ASP.NET_SessionId=okonm4wfhg5ddup5e0wkp0ur; BIGipServerfdic_Forward_prod_80=172495532.20480.0000; _ga=GA1.2.77529009.1621351450; _gid=GA1.2.1620156842.1621351450',
 'Host': 'cdr.ffiec.gov',
 'Origin': 'https://cdr.ffiec.gov',
 'Referer': 'https://cdr.ffiec.gov/Public/ViewFacsimileDirect.aspx?ds=call&idType=fdiccert&id=8426&date=03312021',
 'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="89", "Chromium";v="89", ";Not A Brand";v="99"',
 'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
 'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
 'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
 'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
 'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36' }

# Form data
post_form_data = 
{ "__EVENTTARGET": "",
"__EVENTARGUMENT": "",
"__VIEWSTATE": "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",
"__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR": "A250BEAE",
"ctl00$MainContentHolder$viewTabStrip$Download_PDF_2": "Download PDF" }

# url to submit the form
url = 'https://cdr.ffiec.gov/Public/ViewPDFFacsimile.aspx?ds=call&idType=fdiccert&id=8426&date=03312021'

# making request
resp = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=post_form_data)

# writing the file from response content
with open('file_name.pdf', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(resp.content)
```

**Find the document with specific `fileid` and `date`:** 
this information is given in url params: `... /ViewPDFFacsimile.aspx?ds=call&idType=fdiccert&id=8426&date=03312021'`
You can also find it on the Network tab (in Chrome it called "Query String Parameters"). To pass it in the request, use `params` argument of the `request.post()` method.

```
url_params = { 
"ds": "call",
"idType": "fdiccert",
"id": "8426", 
"date": "03312021" }

request.post(url, headers=headers, data=post_form_data, params=params)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked about 'requests' but I think its easy with Selenium. Try this if you want:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

id = input("id: ")
date = input("date: ")

url = f"https://cdr.ffiec.gov/Public/ViewFacsimileDirect.aspx?ds=call&idType=fdiccert&id={id}&date={date}"

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
el = browser.find_element_by_id("Download_PDF_2")
el.click()
sleep(5)
browser.quit()
```

You can change how you get the id and the date value and sleep time also

Be sure to make chromedriver available in PATH or keep it in same directory as the script